# Поиск и замена текста в MS Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word

Как заменить найденный текст с использованием регулярного выражения?

Сейчас я открываю документ Word через olecontainer и ищу текст с помощью регулярного выражения, далее спрашиваю, нужно ли заменить и если да, то меняю на текст. А как заменить не на текст, а на регулярное выражение (результат)?

```
var
 w: Variant;
begin
  w := oWord.OleObject.Application.Selection;
  w.Find.MatchWildCards := True;
  if w.Find.Execute(AFind) then
    if application.MesageBox('хотите заменить') then
      w.TypeText(AReplace);
```

где

```
AFind:='(<[0-9]@>)[^0032^s](<тысяч>)'
    AReplace:='\1^sтыс.
```

В Word предложение "200 тысяч" должно замениться на "200 тыс.", если пользователь ответит на вопрос.

Comment: Используйте не `w.TypeText`, а (в синтаксисе VBA) `w.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll`

Comment: мне не подходит такой вариант. Мне пользователю нужно задать вопрос, если найдено, и если он ответит да, то только тогда заменить